# How to resolve the Gesture conflict with webView and its subview？

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uigesturerecognizer

I want to add double click gesture to my webview, but not intercept its own click callback，I a subview to response double click gesture , but click callback of the webview will be invalid

```
{
    webMaskView = UIView()
    webVie w.addSubview(webMaskView)
    webMaskView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.right.top.bottom.equalTo(webV)
    }
    let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(webViewTwoTaped(_ :)))
    doubleTap.delegate = self
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    webMaskView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
    webMaskView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    webMaskView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: What about directly adding double tap recogniser to Web View itself?

Comment: Are you using UIWebView or WKWebView from Webkit framework?

Answer (score 2):

You no need to add subview for double tap gesture, You can add double tap gesture directly on Webview or WKWebView.